# Unity - shadows jagged, no solutions?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, light, shadows

I have tried everything said here https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/125619/jagged-shadows-with-default-settings and I have shadows in Unity that are jagged/ugly looking that I need to fix.

Here are my settings in Quality and light:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is what Im getting -

[image]

I want nice clean, non-jagged shadows. What is wrong here?

Comment: The answer from the duplicate may solve your problem. If not, please let me know and I will re-open it

Comment: Sorry - but yes that pixel light solution did not work for me

Comment: I have re-opened it

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, and already tried the other post you've linked to.

[image]

However, after changing `Project Settings > Quality > Shadow Projection` from **Stable Fit** to **Close Fit**, I got a better result:

[image]

From the unity docs, it says:

> There are two different methods for projecting shadows from a directional light. Close Fit renders higher resolution shadows but they can sometimes wobble slightly if the camera moves. Stable Fit renders lower resolution shadows but they don’t wobble with camera movements.

Comment: Can I set the projection in URP as well or only in built-in pipeline?

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue and it seemed like no matter what I did, it would not change. Then on a whim I changed the Shadow Resolution to Very High Resolution and it fixed the issue. Apparently, Ultra cannot have a lower Shadow Resolution than Very High Resolution. Hope this helps.